# Why do the functions run as soon as my code runs? Turtle and TKinter problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-turtle

What should happen is that I run the code, the TKinter window opens and you just click a button, turtle opens and draws the shape.

However when I run my code the Tkinter window and the turtle window open but it just instantly starts drawing the shapes. Also the Tkinter window doesn't have any of the buttons either.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. Please can I have some help.

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle as t

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

def square():
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.exitonclick

def triangle():
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(135)
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(115)
    t.forward(200)
    t.exitonclick

def rectangle():
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.exitonclick

b1 = tk.Button(window, command=square(), text="Square", bg="Red")
b2 = tk.Button(window, command=triangle(), text="Triangle", bg="Cyan")
b3 = tk.Button(window, command=rectangle(), text="Rectangle", bg="Gold")

b1.place(x=0,y=0)
b2.place(x=0,y=30)
b3.place(x=0,y=60)

window.mainloop
```

Comment: It should be `command=square` without parentheses. You want to tell the button which function to run, not give it the output of the function by running it immediately.

Comment: You don't call `window.mainloop` at the end of your code - note the lack of parentheses this time...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you define `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`. When you put the parentheses, the function runs. So you need to remove the parentheses like this:

```py
b1 = tk.Button(window, command=square, text="Square", bg="Red")
b2 = tk.Button(window, command=triangle, text="Triangle", bg="Cyan")
b3 = tk.Button(window, command=rectangle, text="Rectangle", bg="Gold")
```

Comment: I removed the parentheses but now no windows open up

Comment: You need to click button after that turtle window opens. I mean it wouldn't open if you just run it

Comment: If you want turtle window to open with tkinter, then - `t.Screen()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the function name, not calling it so your code will be this:

```
b1 = tk.Button(window, command=square, text="Square", bg="Red")
b2 = tk.Button(window, command=triangle, text="Triangle", bg="Cyan")
b3 = tk.Button(window, command=rectangle, text="Rectangle", bg="Gold")
```

You code will not run because you write `window.mainloop` at the end of the file without calling it, so replace that with `window.mainloop()`

You also need to call `t.exitonclick()`